# Image upload, ajax, php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, image, upload

I have one question.
Is possible upload image from file input to MySQL with Ajax POST and PHP?

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#form_id").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
                data:image_data,
                url:"/path_to_php/ImageSave.php",
                success: function(msg){
                        alert("ok");
                    }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
</script>
<form name="form_name" id="form_id" action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: yes you can store image files in MYSQL databases, just use the BLOB column type.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upload file and store it on database can be done by several ways. [this is one tutorial for doing this.](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2000/09/15/php_mysql.html). But the problem is if you want to do that using Ajax, it is definitely possible, [check this out](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) but almost common browser doesnt support it, the solution is:

- using iframe: [check this tutorial](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/ajax-file-uploads-with-the-iframe-method/)
- using jquery plugin [check this article](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-plugins/)

Comment: Thanks for answer and your help. I solved problem with [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) script.

Comment: Is possible send form data WITH image in mysql with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
     var form_data = $('#reg_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/path_to_php/ImageSave.php",
        data:form_data,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#info").html(data);
        }

    });
    }); 

    });
    </script>
```